# Join dataframe iteratively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a long list and I want to iteratively `join` them to produce a final dataframe.

The data is originally in `dict` so I need to iterate over the dictionary first.

```
header = ['apple', 'pear', 'cocoa']


for key, value in data.items():
    
    for idx in header:

        # Flatten the dictionary to dataframe
        data_df = pd.json_normalize(data[key][idx])
        # Here I start to lose.....
```

How can I iteratively `join` the dataframe?

Manually it can be done like this:

```
data_df = pd.json_normalize(data["ParentKey"]['apple'])

data_df1 = pd.json_normalize(data["ParentKey"]['pear'])

final_df = data_df1.join(data_df, lsuffix='_left')

# or

final_df = pd.concat([data_df, data_df1], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Since the list will be large, I want to iterate them instead.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: would you like to see output example? @rafaelc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You can use k as a counter to indicate whether or not it's the first iterator and then for future ones just join it to that same dataframe:

```
header = ['apple', 'pear', 'cocoa']

for key, value in data.items():
  
  k = 0
  for idx in header:
    data_df = pd.json_normalize(data[key][idx])
    if k==0:
      final_df = data_df
    else:
      final_df = final_df.join(data_df, lsuffix='_left')
    k += 1
```

Comment: yes exactly this. silly thing I cant wrap my head around. Thanks!

Comment: @cna Please consider accepting and upvoting answer if it solves the problem.